# Checking tree modifications in django-treebeard ORM before saving

Tags: django, django-orm, django-treebeard

I want to double-check if I am correctly interpreting the following section of the [django-treebeard](http://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/caveats.html) docs:

> django-treebeard uses Django raw SQL queries for some write operations, and raw queries don’t update the objects in the ORM since it’s being bypassed.
>
> Because of this, if you have a node in memory and plan to use it after a tree modification (adding/removing/moving nodes), you need to reload it.

Here's my understanding:

If I've loaded a node from the database and am working on it in memory, I must use [refresh_from_db()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#refreshing-objects-from-database) before saving. Also, in case the tree is modified between refresh_from_db and save, I should wrap the two calls in an atomic transaction.

Is this correct?